# my jquery does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a wordpress site, in which I have design tabs.
I want that when I click on first tab, it should display the contents of the div with id=tab1.

And when I click on the second tab it should display the cotent of the div with id=tab2.

But nothing is working.

Here is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide all content
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    //Activate first tab
    $(".tabs_links ul li:first").addClass("active").show();
    //Show first tab content
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
    //On Click Event
    $(".tabs_links ul li").click(function() {
        //Remove any "active" class
        $(".tabs_links ul li").removeClass("active");
        //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(this).addClass("active");
        //Hide all tab content
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        //Fade in the active content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

and here is my html code.

```
<div class="tabs_links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">News and Events</a></li>
        <li><a class="nobg" href="#tab4">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    content of first tab
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="tab4" class="tab_content">
    content of second tab
</div>
```

I don't know what is the problem. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: why not use jQueryUI tabs... : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: the code seems to work just fine : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/MeMZv/ . Maybe you didn't setup some script references.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to do little css stuff :) Working Test page with your code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.tabs_links ul li{display:inline;}
a{text-decoration:none;color:black;}
.active{background-color:#CECECE;}
.tab_content{margin-left:30px;border:1px dotted black;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tab_content").hide(); 
$(".tabs_links ul li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
$(".tab_content:first").show();

    $(".tabs_links ul li").click(function() {
            $(".tabs_links ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active"); 
            $(".tab_content").hide(); 
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
            return false;
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs_links">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#tab1">News & Events</a></li>
              <li><a class="nobg" href="#tab4">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
<div style="display: none;" id="tab1" class="tab_content">
First First First First First First 
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="tab4" class="tab_content">
Second Second Second Second Second Second 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I checked your code, its working fine when create a new html page. But in wordpress it did not work. I am displaying all this on index.php

Comment: Let me debug your working page. What is the link of wordpress website ?

Comment: Instead of linking local jquery, try using above google api jquery once inside script tag. <script src=""></script>

Comment: i am not able to detect the problem with the info provided by you. Try to debug in FF with the help of Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well.

I think problem is your browser or jQuery plugin

Use jQuery 1.4.2 plugin

Comment: I used this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>` but did not work as well.